# How to find the number of unique names from list of paired data having chained information?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have got 'n' rows of data sets, each data set having two components separated by space. First is card number and second is name. A person is same, if he has same card number or the name. How to find the total number of unique person from the data set?

Example:

1 A

1 B

2 B

3 C

This data set has 2 unique person. This is because the first and second row card number is same and second and third row name is same.

What kind of algorithms can be used to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: what is the result if I added `3 B`? think carefully.

Comment: Then the result will be 1 as all the names are chained.

Comment: Then I think you're asking how to find the number of connected components of graph. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: Sorry, but wouldn't the count be zero.  With all the names linked, there'd be no unique person.

Comment: hmm, There must at least one person. You can't have zero persons unless you have 0 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is using some sort of partitioning: Most operation are done in O(1) or O(logn) and it is done once by user, therefor the time complexity is about O(n),O(logn) depending on how Dictionary are implemented.

```
int CountUnique(Person persons)
{
        Dictionary<string, int> phones = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //Keep a dictionary where each phone number is mapped to a partition
        Dictionary<string, int> email = new Dictionary<string, int>();  //Keep a dictionary where each email is mapped to a partition
        bool[,] linked = new bool[n, n]; //Lookup table used to tell if 2 partitions are linked (represents the same person)
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Person p = persons[i];
            int pA = -1, pB = -1; // Partition found using the phone number, Partition found using email
            if (phones.ContainsKey(p.Phone))
            {
                pA = phones[p.Phone];
            }
            if (emails.ContainsKey(p.Email))
            {
                pB = emails[p.Email];
            }

            if (pA == -1 && pB == -1) // First case, not found: Add both phones and email and create a new partition. Number of unique persons is also incremented.
            {
                phones.Add(p.Phone.Trim(), max);
                emails.Add(p.Email.Trim().ToLower(), max);
                max++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (pA != -1 && pB != -1 && pA != pB) // Found using both parameters on different partitions
                {
                    if (!linked[pA, pB] && !linked[pB, pA]) // If the partition are not linked, link them
                    {
                        count--; // We'lost one partition => one unique person less
                        linked[pA, pB] = linked[pB, pA] = true;
                    }
                }
                if (pA == -1) // We did find an existing email but no phone
                {
                    phones.Add(p.Phone.Trim(), pB); // Add the phone number
                    max++;
                }
                if (pB == -1) // We did find an existing phone but no email
                {
                    emails.Add(p.Email.Trim().ToLower(), pA); // Add the email number
                    max++;
                }
            }

        }



return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using graph theory and Connected components:

```
              int CountUnique(Person[] persons)
                Dictionary<string, int> phones = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                Dictionary<string, int> emails = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                bool[] unique = new bool[n];
                int count = 0;
                int max = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    Person p = persons[i];
                    int pA = -1, pB = -1;
                    if (phones.ContainsKey(p.Phone))
                    {
                        pA = phones[p.Phone];
                    }
                    if (emails.ContainsKey(p.Email))
                    {
                        pB = emails[p.Email];
                    }
                    if (pA != -1)
                    {
                        persons[pA].Next.Add(p);
                        p.Next.Add(persons[pA]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        phones.Add(p.Phone, p.Index);
                    }

                    if (pB != -1 && pB != pA)
                    {
                        persons[pB].Next.Add(p);
                        p.Next.Add(persons[pB]);
                    }
                    if (pB == -1)
                    {
                        emails.Add(p.Email, p.Index);
                    }
                }


                int current = 0;
                Person pCurrent;
                count = 0;
                while ((pCurrent = FindUnvisited(persons, current)) != null)
                {
                    BFS(pCurrent);
                    count++;
                }

                return count;


            }

            private static void DFS(Person pCurrent)
            {
                pCurrent.Visited = true;
                foreach (Person p in pCurrent.Next)
                {
                    if (!p.Visited)
                    {
                        BFS(p);
                    }
                }
            }

            private static Person FindUnvisited(Person[] persons, int current)
            {
                for (int i = current; i < persons.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (persons[i].Visited == false) return persons[i];
                }
                return null;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: quick one.. what does BFS stand for?  for the life of me, I can't sus it out. More to the point, what does it do?  I mean if you didn't have the code in front of you.. Yea this is a bit of trolling, but function names are important.

Comment: @daveatflow, [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) BFS is a very common abbreviation for that among people who studied graph theory, discrete math, algorithms etc... a *lot* of jargon gets used in posts with the [algorithm] tag :). Also, I think these tree traversal algorithms are somewhat difficult to jump into and understand for someone new to the subject.

Comment: It should be DFS (depth-first search) not BFS (breadth-first search) which is the recursive form (using a stack),sorry, fixed it. The main idea is to visit a node, find all the nodes that are adjacent(linked) and recurse over them keeping track of the ones already visited to avoid infinite loop. This algorithm process all nodes once therefor it does discover a Connected component in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Sort of C++.  But take it as pseudo code.

```
int uniqueCount = 0;
map<string, bool> column_1;
map<string, bool> column_2;
string left, right
for(int x = 0 ;x < matrix.count; x++) {
   left = matrix[x][0]
   right = matrix[x][1];
   if(column_1.find(left) != column_1.end && column_2.find(right) != column_2.end){
  ++uniqueCount 
   column_1[left] = true;
   column_2[right] = true;
   }
  else --uniqueCount;
}
```

I'm sorry if the above doesn't compile.  Take it as pseudo code, I've not been in c++ for a while, and didn't think the rails code would be as helpful.

Comment: of course adjust types depending on need.  left column might be ints